# Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have a question.
If I have a complex function and I know that for $r=1$, $f(z=e^{iθ})=\cos(θ)\sin(θ)$
And I know that $f(z)$ is entire.
Now, I need to calculate $f'(z)$ for every $z$ in $r=1$, meaning $z=e^{iθ}$.
I tried to define $u(r,θ)= \cos(θ)\sin(θ)$,
$v(r,θ)= 0$
And use Cauchy-Riemann Equations in polar coordinates..and then I get that the derivative is zero, but I am not sure cause I can calculate the derivative by definition (derivative by $θ$) and then I got something which is a function of $θ$ so I am a bit confused..why is that? What is the right way to calculate it?

Answer (score 3):

$f(z)=\frac 1 {4i} (z^{2}-\frac 1 {z^{2}})$  whenever $|z|=1$. By Identity Theorem we must have $f(z)=\frac 1 {4i} (z^{2}-\frac 1 {z^{2}})$  for all $z \neq 0$, so $f$ cannot be continuous at $0$. Hence, there is no such entire function.

If you consider $f$ as an analytic function on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ then we can compute $f'(z)$ easily: $f'(z)=\frac 1 {4i} (2z+\frac 2 {z^{3}})$. This is valid for all $z \neq 0$, in particular for $|z|=1$.

Comment: you mean there is a contradiction it the question and it is not valid?
this is also what I thought but it makes no sense my lecturer will ask a question which is not valid..
I mean..it is given in the question that the function is entire..

Comment: Well, mistakes do occur sometimes. The question is not valid. @LidorHacham

Comment: @LidorHacham if you ignore the problem at $0$ consider $f$ as an analytic function on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ then you can calculate $f'(z)$ from the formula I wrote.

Comment: ok so let's say it is analytic on C∖{0} , still Cauchy-Riemann Equations should hold for r=1, and if I use them I get that f′(z) = 0..what is the problem at using this method?

Comment: To find $f'(z)$ for $z$ on the circle you cannot restrict yourselves to points on the circle. The definition of derivative demands that you consider arbitrary seqeneces $z_n$ converging to $z$, even points with $|z_n| \neq 1$.  @LidorHacham

Comment: why not? if f is diffrentiable at any point so we can derivative by any path.
anyway because of what you did i undertood why using Cauchy-Riemann Equations doesn't work here.. I'll try to calculate the derivative by your method and I think it will be the same answer

Comment: ok so if I'm using your way (which seems to be correct), how do I calculate the derivative for |z|=1?

Comment: From the answer shown, $f^\prime(e^{i\theta}) = \frac{1}{4i}(2e^{i\theta}+2e^{-3i\theta}).$